# Linearly disjoint of local fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

If $K$ and $L$ are two number fields such that $K\cap L = \mathbb{Q}$, then can we say something about the intersection of two local fields satisfy $K_{\mathfrak{B_1}}\cap L_{\mathfrak{B_2}} = \mathbb{Q}_p$, where $\mathfrak{B_1}\cap\mathbb{Q} = \mathfrak{B_2}\cap\mathbb{Q} = p  $?
or "are there some conditions or theorems can make this fact hold?"
I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: No. For example, if $p$ is unramified in both $K$ and $L$ then for any two primes $\mathfrak{p}_K, \mathfrak{p}_L$ of $K$ and $L$, respectively,  lying over $p$, the intersection of the corresponding completions is equal to $\mathbf{Q}_p$ if and only if their inertia degrees are relatively prime.

Comment: There are far fewer extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ than there are of $\mathbb Q$, so even if $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\not\cong\mathbb Q(\beta)$, it may still be the case that  $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)\not\cong\mathbb Q_p(\beta)$. For example, $\mathbb Q_p(1-\zeta_p) = \mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[p-1]{-p})$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter, thank you, but I am wondering if there are some conditions can make this fact hold. reference? theorem?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Got it! thank you.

Comment: @EricPark I just gave you one. Since all but finitely many primes are unramified in both $K$ and $L$, this is the most common situation you would encounter. Saying something in the ramified case will be more difficult.

Comment: @BrandonCarter got it! Is there any reference related to your example? also some references are related to ramified cases. Thank you very much!

Comment: @EricPark You should try proving it for yourself. It follows almost immediately as long as you know that $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}_p^{nr}/\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{F}_p}/\mathbf{F}_p)$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter More precisely, I would like to know if $p$ is ramified in both $K$ and $L$ is there any condition can make this hold? Thank you again!

Comment: @ThomasPark, the words, “$p$ is ramified in $K$” conceal a multitude of phenomena, when the degree $[K:\Bbb Q]$ is not two. Maybe $p$ splits into two primes, both ramified. Or, if the extension is not Galois, maybe $p$ splits into two primes, one of degree one, the other of higher degree, but ramified. Things can get very convoluted. If you can, you should look at some nonquadratic fields; maybe cyclotomic examples would be most easily investigated.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you very much for your comment. I will try to work what you said.